# Error launching android studio.. environment variable does not point to valid JVM installation

Tags: android-studio

The environment variable JAVA_HOME(C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin) does not point to a valid JVM installation.

I am getting this error when am launching android-studio.. And i also Tried similar questions in stack-overflow but nothing worked. am using 32bit

I set the variables as:

variable name  : JAVA_HOME
Variable value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin

Answer (score 11):

Change the JAVA_HOME into C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05

Comment: still am getting the same error.. what else could the problem??

Comment: Reset eclipse to get the new value of JAVA_HOME

Answer (score 0):

Point your JAVA_HOME variable to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_xx\; where "xx" is the update number (make sure this matches your actual system directory name).

NOTE: 
be sure to put the 'JAVA_HOME' path variable in the System variables rather      than -the user variables. If the path variable is in User the Android Studio will   not find the path.